# Callback for AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor()

Tags: javascript, people-picker

Hi I'm usering **AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor()** to add users to a SharePoint (2013) people picker... This works great, but takes an eternity (5 seconds).

I found dozens of tutorial how to use that method but actually no documentation.

Is there a way to use this function synchronously, or add a callback?
is there any official documentation? Does anybody know what the parameter actually does (it always sais: AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(*true*))??

-thx

Comment: I did this gist https://gist.github.com/Aymkdn/5925efc9f4fecccc40612c6a5db7efc9/comments/1957393 where you can find some useful code to deal with peoplepicker. I'm currently on vacation and posting from my phone so it's difficult to provide more info here, but look at the gist : it contains comments and examples. It's to create a homemade people picker field and it will trigger a "user:changed" event and to do so I used a setInterval because I didn't find any other solution.

Comment: Thanks... the url leads to 404... 
Actually everything is working fine. I just need a callback. I can't build another people picker field... running out of time (budget ;-)

Comment: Sorry for the link. Here is the correct one : https://gist.github.com/Aymkdn/5925efc9f4fecccc40612c6a5db7efc9/ And because there is no callback, you'll have to do a content check of the field to detect when it has been updated, just as I did on the gist